# Alachisoft.NCache.Runtime.Exceptions.OperationFailedException: Cache is not initialized

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, caching, ncache

We are using NCache as a 2nd level cache for NHibernate.

A local console test app is able to retrieve items from the cache.

However in our web app we receive 'Cache is not initialized'

We are using WCF to connect through a front site to a back site which runs the queries.

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if it exact same issue, we faced couple of days ago. Seems your cache name is incorrect in the configuration, try correcting the same and restart your Ncache service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem to this was the way we were registering our backend WCF services with Castle.

Using 'PerWcfOperation' or any other registration apart from Transient caused this error.

Set our service lifecycles to Transient and it works as expected.

Will look through the Castle source to find out why.